# Anchor dependency issue

Tags: anchor

got an dependency issue when trying to build anchor

My anchor version:

```
>>> anchor --version
anchor-cli 0.24.1
```

I've initialized project:

```
anchor init solana-escrow-anchor
```

Then, move into directory to compile this:

```
>>> anchor build    
BPF SDK: /Users/n.duginets/.local/share/solana/install/releases/stable-616d8d67978c325087cc5a9f33307f54eee48b6e/solana-release/bin/sdk/bpf
cargo-build-bpf child: rustup toolchain list -v
cargo-build-bpf child: cargo +bpf build --target bpfel-unknown-unknown --release
warning: profiles for the non root package will be ignored, specify profiles at the workspace root:
package:   /Users/n.duginets/IdeaProjects/solana-escrow-anchor/programs/solana-escrow-anchor/Cargo.toml
workspace: /Users/n.duginets/IdeaProjects/solana-escrow-anchor/Cargo.toml
    Updating crates.io index
error: failed to select a version for the requirement `aho-corasick = "^1.0.0"`
candidate versions found which didn't match: 0.7.20, 0.7.19, 0.7.18, ...
location searched: crates.io index
required by package `regex v1.8.1`
    ... which satisfies dependency `regex = "^1.0"` (locked to 1.8.1) of package `anchor-attribute-access-control v0.27.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `anchor-attribute-access-control = "^0.27.0"` (locked to 0.27.0) of package `anchor-lang v0.27.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `anchor-lang = "^0.27.0"` (locked to 0.27.0) of package `solana-escrow-anchor v0.1.0 (/Users/n.duginets/IdeaProjects/solana-escrow-anchor/programs/solana-escrow-anchor)`
```

And got this strange error.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

According to the error notice, there is a dependency issue with the version of the "aho-corasick" crate. The version required by the "regex" crate and several of the dependencies of the "solana-escrow-anchor" project are incompatible.

You can try one of the following fixes to resolve this problem:

- List item: The "solana-escrow-anchor" project's Cargo.toml file should be modified to match the version requirement of the "regex" crate for the "aho-corasick" crate. To ensure compatibility with the most recent version of the "regex" crate, you can try altering the "1.0.0" requirement to "0.7.0." Run the "anchor build" command once more after that.
- List item: Update the version of the "regex" crate to one that is compatible with the version of "aho-corasick" required by the other dependencies if altering the version requirement of the "aho-corasick" crate is not possible. Change the "regex" crate's version requirement in the "solana-escrow-anchor" project's Cargo.toml file to do this. Run the "anchor build" command once more after that.
- List item: Utilising a dependency resolver tool, such as "cargo-edit" or "cargo-tree" to examine the dependency tree and identify the problem's underlying causes, is another option. These tools can show you which versions of the dependencies are incompatible and offer a potential fix.

Comment: I've tried all of these items, still the same error

Comment: resolved with updating anchor to 0.27.0 and solana to 1.15.2

Comment: Stop copying chatGPT as answers